# Morphia check for empty array field

Tags: java, morphia

Using morphia how can i query for records which their "items" field which is of type array is empty - has no itmes

I tried this:

```
userQueryDS.field("items").greaterThan(0);
```

But this obviously dont work giving this error:

> The type(s) for the query/update may be inconsistent; using an instance of type 'java.lang.Integer' for the field 'com.model.User.devices' which is declared as 'java.util.List'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Both variants should work.

```
userQueryDS.criteria("items").sizeEq(0);

userQueryDS.field("items").sizeEq(0);
```